# Trying to understand how ASP.NET .XSL gets/saves data to/from a database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xslt

This is probably a old topic.  I have an older ASP.NET application that I'm charged with modifying.  I've not used this technology before.  I see in the .xls files, things like <xls:value-of select="..." /> which seems to return values from the database.

I've done some searching but keep coming up with nothing relevant.  Prolly because I'm using the wrong search strings.  I have access to the database and the .xsl files but there's no .xml files or .xslt files in the project that I have (no project files either for that matter).  Other than "<xls:value-of... />", I've no idea how the data in the database gets to the web page.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: .xsl and .xslt file extensions can be used interchangeably. Without more info it's hard to tell what's going on, but there could possibly be an XML representation of the data in memory (no XML file) to which your xslt transformation has access?

Comment: `<xls:value-of select="..." />` <-- you left out the important part (where the `...` is). You don't have to show us the exact text but some pattern would be helpful. Also there must be a data connection associated with the file or something...

Comment: Thank you.  I think I've figured it out.  I have the frontend code, but none of the middleware/backend code which is where the data from the database comes from.  I'm going to create my own server to serve up the data I need and invoke http calls from JS get it.  Thank you.  Apologies for the inane question.

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what to suggest here. This suggests that the dataset designer was used. How this works is REALLY very much like EF (entity frameworks). The dataset designer is a typical ORM (Object relational management system).

In fact, using the dataset designer is VERY much like using EF.

However, the dataset designer does NOT let you set/use a database connection string.
(you choose one WHEN creating the dataset). But you no doubt have a defined connection anyway. If you change that connection string, then the dataset designers will now use that changed connection string anyway.

Like EF? Well, do you really care much how it works, or do you just care that you have the tables as some data model? I tend to not care anything more then

Hey, do I have a table - can I use it? can I feed the results to say a gridview or some such? So in effect, what you REALLY care about is how to use those data objects in code.

So, then you don't care if the database is Oracle, MySQL, SQL server, or even MS-Access.

When you open/launch say a xsd file in vs? the dataset desinger should launch.

So, You see this:

[image]

So, the above is 100% the SAME regardless of the actaual database being used. As noted, it could be MS-Access or Oracle - I don't care. In BOTH cases or in fact regadless of the database enigne, I will STILL get the above, and NOT have to change my code or care about the database in question.

So, we can for example write out in code to fill a grid view. (that's what we often call database first, or simply that we don't use EF, or the older datasets - which I noted are the same idea).

So, say I drop a grid view onto a page.

[image]

So, to fill the Grid, I might have this
(just code - no EF or Dataset designer used).

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub
```

Sub LoadGrid()

```
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT TOP 10 FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Description
             FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName"

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

            conn.Open()
            GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And now I have this:

[image]

But, in place of typing in specific sql server syntax, and building that data table in code?

I would consider using EF or the older dataset designer.

so, I can add a new query in the dataset designer.

[image]

So, now we have a really nice "central" means to see our database schema, and a nice central place to say add queries and manage the data model.

This means I don't have in-line SQL tossed around in the code base like spaghetti.

So adding store procedure methods (with parameters), general queries, and a REALLY nice 50,000 foot view of the data model is why we use EF , or the older dataset designer. This so called ORM approach is common used.

So, now the above code, say based on my dataset, and that query I added to/in the dataset designer? I can now use that one query over and over in code.

I added the new query and called it GetMyHotels

[image]

So, now my code to fill the grid view becomes this:

```
  Dim Mydt As New TEST4TableAdapters.tblHotelsTableAdapter

    GridView1.DataSource = Mydt.GetMyHotels
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

And I even get intel-sense for "GetMyHotels"

So, you don't now mess with SQL or even connection strings in code. You have a "object" that is your database.